# Hide the section from same form

Tags: vb.net, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm currently writing an approval system. In the system consist of 1 request form. That form divided into 3 section. section A, B, C. Section A for requester use, section B for manager use and section C for security use. Now my problem is I want to hide section B and C from the requester.

```
   'A.Requestor

    req_emNo.Text = req_emNo.Text
    reqDept.Text = reqDept.Text
    reqDate.Text = reqDate.Text
    Purpose.Text = Purpose.SelectedItem.Text
    rturn.Text = rturn.SelectedItem.Text
    AppMgr.Text = AppMgr.SelectedItem.Text
    Me.MgrName.Visible = False
    Me.MgrEmpNo.Visible = False
    Me.MgrDept.Visible = False
```

But its just hide the text box only. Please suggest how to the overall section B, and C. Thank you.

Comment: What are you using to section your form?

Comment: for the section A requester fill up the details send to manager. section B for manager, they need to approve the request form

Comment: Yes, you said, but how are the controls separated, are they in a grouping of any sort, or are they just layed out in groups?  Might a tabcontrol be what you need, so you can hide tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the controls of each "Section" into a Panel control. Then you can hide the panel which hides all the controls inside it. For example...

```
Panel1.Visible = False
```